# How can "multiple folders/files" be deleted in ONE PSEXEC COMMAND LINE

Tags: batch-file, file-io, remote-server, psexec

I can delete remote folders/files via bat command with psexec (below) but; 
It takes a little time because of the 9 different folders. Maybe, looping of txt file can be used for different folders.

So how we can delete multiple folders in **ONE PSEXEC COMMAND LINE?**

Here my working code but it does its job in 9 steps :(

```
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\1*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\2*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\3*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\4*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\5*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\6*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\7*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\8*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\9*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\T*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /l %%n in (1;1;9) do  for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\%%n*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""
```

Comment: Can you add for T*.* to your code

    psexec \\%PC% cmd /c "for /d %%a in ("c:\Users\T*.*") do rd /s /q "%%a""